# How do I push new data in an array stored in Firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've got my data stored in Firestore as follows:

[image]

Its data is retrieved as follows:

```
created () {
    db.collection('cards').where('user', '==', this.user)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const data = {
            'id': doc.id,
            'group_name': doc.data().group_name,
            'group': doc.data().group,
            'size': doc.data().group.length
          }
          this.cards.push(data)
        })
      })
  }
```

And finally rendered in the following way:

```
 <div v-for="(card, groupIndex) in cards" v-bind:key="card.id" class="card-group">....</div>
```

All works as desired. The thing is how do I add a new slot with data to the `group`-array in firestore. After having searched the internet it seems that it's not possible to push new data in an array stored in firestore. Is this true or are there possibilities?

If not possible do I need to store my data as an object and how do I `v-for` true its content?

below the complete code:

```
<template>
  <div id="dashboard">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 50px">
      <div v-for="(card, groupIndex) in cards" v-bind:key="card.id" class="card-group">
      <div :id="card.group_name" class="card-group-header" @click="toggleChild" >{{card.group_name}}
        <div class="group-count-label"> {{card.size}} </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div :id="card.group_name + 'B'" class="dropdown-arrow"></div>
          <div style="margin-right:10px;font-size:15px">&#8942;</div>
          </div>
      </div>
        <div class="card-group-items hidden-group" :id="card.group_name + 'A'">
          <div v-for="(value, index) in card.group" v-bind:key="index" class="collection-item">
            <div :id="card.group_name + index" class="card-group-item-header" @click="toggleItem" >
              <div class="card-group-item-header-text">
                <div class="card-group-item-header-text-front">{{value.front}}</div>
                <div class="card-group-item-header-text-back">{{value.back}}</div>
              </div>
              <div class="right">
                <div :id="card.group_name + index + 'B'" class="dropdown-arrow-b"></div>
                <div style="margin:7px 10px 0px 0px;font-size:15px">&#8942;</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ITEM -->
              <div :id="card.group_name + index + 'A'" class="card-group-item">
                <div>
                  <div class="textbox-tip">Front</div>
                  <input type="text" class="card-group-item-input" :value="value.front" spellcheck="false">
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="textbox-tip">Back</div>
                  <input type="text" class="card-group-item-input" :value="value.back" spellcheck="false">
                </div>
                <!-- CARD EXAMPLES -->
                <div class="card-group-examples">
                  <div class="card-group-example-header"><div>Examples</div><div class="card-group-example-header-plus" @click="addExample(groupIndex,index)">&#43;</div></div>
                  <div v-for="(v, i) in value.examples" v-bind:key="i">
                    <div>
                      <div class="textbox-tip">Example {{i+1}}</div>
                      <input type="text" class="card-group-item-input" :value="v.example" spellcheck="false">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="textbox-tip">Answer {{i+1}}</div>
                      <input type="text" class="card-group-item-input" :value="v.answer" spellcheck="false">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-group-item-footer">
                  <button class="button" @click="saveUpdate(groupIndex,index,card.id)" >SAVE CHANGES</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="button" @click="test" >SAVE new</button>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import db from './firebaseInit'
export default {
  name: 'dashboard',
  data () {
    return {
      cards: [],
      user: 'kikker'
    }
  },
  created () {
    db.collection('cards').where('user', '==', this.user)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const data = {
            'id': doc.id,
            'group_name': doc.data().group_name,
            'group': doc.data().group,
            'size': doc.data().group.length
          }
          this.cards.push(data)
        })
      })
  },
  methods: {
    toggleChild (i) {
      var x = document.getElementById(i.target.id + 'A')
      var y = document.getElementById(i.target.id + 'B')
      if (x.style.display === 'none' || x.style.display === '') {
        x.style.display = 'block'
        y.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(45deg)'
        y.style.margin = '5px 5px 0px 0px'
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none'
        y.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(-45deg)'
        y.style.margin = '7px 5px 0px 0px'
      }
    },
    toggleItem (i) {
      var x = document.getElementById(i.target.id + 'A')
      var y = document.getElementById(i.target.id + 'B')

      if (x.style.display === 'none' || x.style.display === '') {
        x.style.display = 'block'
        y.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(45deg)'
        y.style.margin = '13px 5px 0px 0px'
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none'
        y.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(-45deg)'
        y.style.margin = '15px 5px 0px 0px'
      }
    },
    addExample (x, y) {
      this.cards[x].group[y].examples.push({
      })
    },
    saveUpdate (x, y, z) {
      console.log(z)
      db.collection('cards').doc(z).update({
        'age': 13,
        'favorites.color': 'Red'
      })
        .then(function () {
          console.log('Document successfully updated!')
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          alert('Error updating document: (The document probably doesn\'t exist.: )', error)
        })
    },
    test () {
      console.log('vd')

      db.collection('cards').doc('BdSxtZL8V4S576i2BTRs').update({
        group: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({ back: 'bla', front: 'blabla' })
      })

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

firebaseInit.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export default firebaseApp.firestore()
```

firebaseConfig.js

```
export default {
  apiKey: 'blabla',
  authDomain: 'blabla',
  databaseURL: 'blabla',
  projectId: 'blabla',
  storageBucket: 'blabla.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'blabla',
  appId: 'blabla',
  measurementId: 'G-blabla'
}
```

UPDATED CONTENT:

**firebaseInit.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export default firebaseApp.firestore()

const db = firebaseApp.firestore()
const fieldValue = firebaseApp.firestore.FieldValue

export { db, fieldValue }
```

**dahsboard.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="dashboard">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 50px">
      <div v-for="(card, groupIndex) in cards" v-bind:key="card.id" class="card-group">
      <div :id="card.group_name" class="card-group-header" @click="toggleChild" >{{card.group_name}}
        <div class="group-count-label"> {{card.size}} </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div :id="card.group_name + 'B'" class="dropdown-arrow"></div>
          <div style="margin-right:10px;font-size:15px">&#8942;</div>
          </div>
      </div>
        <div class="card-group-items hidden-group" :id="card.group_name + 'A'">
          <div v-for="(value, index) in card.group" v-bind:key="index" class="collection-item">
            <div :id="card.group_name + index" class="card-group-item-header" @click="toggleItem" >
              <div class="card-group-item-header-text">
                <div class="card-group-item-header-text-front">{{value.front}}</div>
                <div class="card-group-item-header-text-back">{{value.back}}</div>
              </div>
              <div class="right">
                <div :id="card.group_name + index + 'B'" class="dropdown-arrow-b"></div>
                <div style="margin:7px 10px 0px 0px;font-size:15px">&#8942;</div>
              </div>
            </div>
              <div :id="card.group_name + index + 'A'" class="card-group-item">
                <div>
                  <div class="textbox-tip">Front</div>
                  <input type="text" class="card-group-item-input" :value="value.front" spellcheck="false">
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="textbox-tip">Back</div>
                  <input type="text" class="card-group-item-input" :value="value.back" spellcheck="false">
                </div>
                <div class="card-group-examples">
                  <div class="card-group-example-header"><div>Examples</div><div class="card-group-example-header-plus" @click="addExample(groupIndex,index)">&#43;</div></div>
                  <div v-for="(v, i) in value.examples" v-bind:key="i">
                    <div>
                      <div class="textbox-tip">Example {{i+1}}</div>
                      <input type="text" class="card-group-item-input" :value="v.example" spellcheck="false">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="textbox-tip">Answer {{i+1}}</div>
                      <input type="text" class="card-group-item-input" :value="v.answer" spellcheck="false">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-group-item-footer">
                  <button class="button" @click="saveUpdate(groupIndex,index,card.id)" >SAVE CHANGES</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="button" @click="test" >SAVE new</button>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { db, fieldValue } from './firebaseInit'
export default {
  name: 'dashboard',
  data () {
    return {
      cards: [],
      user: 'kikker'
    }
  },
  created () {
    db.collection('cards').where('user', '==', this.user)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const data = {
            'id': doc.id,
            'group_name': doc.data().group_name,
            'group': doc.data().group,
            'size': doc.data().group.length
          }
          this.cards.push(data)
        })
      })
  },
  methods: {
    toggleChild (i) {
      var x = document.getElementById(i.target.id + 'A')
      var y = document.getElementById(i.target.id + 'B')
      if (x.style.display === 'none' || x.style.display === '') {
        x.style.display = 'block'
        y.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(45deg)'
        y.style.margin = '5px 5px 0px 0px'
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none'
        y.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(-45deg)'
        y.style.margin = '7px 5px 0px 0px'
      }
    },
    toggleItem (i) {
      var x = document.getElementById(i.target.id + 'A')
      var y = document.getElementById(i.target.id + 'B')

      if (x.style.display === 'none' || x.style.display === '') {
        x.style.display = 'block'
        y.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(45deg)'
        y.style.margin = '13px 5px 0px 0px'
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none'
        y.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(-45deg)'
        y.style.margin = '15px 5px 0px 0px'
      }
    },
    addExample (x, y) {
      this.cards[x].group[y].examples.push({
      })
    },
    saveUpdate (x, y, z) {
      console.log(z)
      db.collection('cards').doc(z).update({
        'age': 13,
        'favorites.color': 'Red'
      })
        .then(function () {
          console.log('Document successfully updated!')
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          alert('Error updating document: (The document probably doesn\'t exist.: )', error)
        })
    },
    test () {
      console.log('vd')

      db.collection('cards').doc('BdSxtZL8V4S576i2BTRs').update({
        group: fieldValue.arrayUnion({ back: 'bla', front: 'blabla' })
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you should use the [`arrayUnion()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-array-union) method: "each specified element that doesn't already exist in the array will be added to the end (of the array)". 
See more detail in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

For that you need to:

1. Change your `firebaseInit.js` file to:

   ```
       import firebase from 'firebase'
       import 'firebase/firestore'
       import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'
       firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

       const db = firebase.firestore();
       const fieldValue = firebase.firestore.FieldValue;

       export { db, fieldValue };
   ```
2. Adapt your component code as follows:

   ```
       <script>
       import { db, fieldValue } from './firebaseInit'
       export default {
       name: 'dashboard',
       data () {
           return {
           cards: [],
           user: 'kikker'
           }
       },
       created () {
           db.collection('cards').where('user', '==', this.user)
           .get()
           .then(querySnapshot => {
               querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
               const data = {
                   'id': doc.id,
                   'group_name': doc.data().group_name,
                   'group': doc.data().group,
                   'size': doc.data().group.length
               }
               this.cards.push(data)
               })
           })
       },
       methods: {
           //....
           test () {
           console.log('vd')

           db.collection('cards').doc('BdSxtZL8V4S576i2BTRs').update({
               group: fieldValue.arrayUnion({ back: 'bla', front: 'blabla' })
           })

           }
       }
       }
       </script>
   ```

Then, if you want to reflect the addition in your front-end there are many possibilities with Vue.js (re-fetch the collection, set a listener, push it to a local array at the same time you write to Firestore,  etc.). You need to give more detail on what is your exact functional requirement.

Comment: I am giving it a try but get an error `firebase is not defined`

Comment: You have to add to your question **all** the code you use for that: from the Firebase configuration in Vue.js up to the way you write to Firestore.

Comment: Can you pls also add the content of the `firebaseInit` file. It is there that you need to export `firebase.firestore.FieldValue`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203464/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-mk01111000).

Comment: @MK01111000 Did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: I did and replied in the discussion chat. Thanks for helping Renaud, I updated my files, but get an error: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayUnion' of undefined"